# How to change the behavior of the beforeAction?

Tags: yii2

There is a beforeAction() in Controller.php

```
public function beforeAction($action)
    {
        if (parent::beforeAction($action)) {
            if ($this->enableCsrfValidation && Yii::$app->getErrorHandler()->exception === null && !Yii::$app->getRequest()->validateCsrfToken()) {
                throw new BadRequestHttpException(Yii::t('yii', 'Unable to verify your data submission.'));
            }
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }
```

It throws an exception but I want to change this in my own controller which extends controller.php. I try something like that

```
public function beforeAction($action) {
    if ($this->enableCsrfValidation && Yii::$app->getErrorHandler()->exception === null && !Yii::$app->getRequest()->validateCsrfToken()) {
        Yii::$app->session->setFlash('info', 'Error');
        $this->goBack();
    }
    return parent::beforeAction($action);
}
```

But it still shows exception.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure but it might work with just changing this row...

```
$this->goBack();
```

into...

```
return $this->goBack();
```

Another approach would be to catch the Exception from the parent instead. Later there might be other events triggered by beforeAction and if not calling the parent::beforeAction these may not be run as intended.